# Should I flag a comment thread for cleanup just because of length?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

Sometimes, answer comment threads get out of hand and are obvious candidates for a flag for a moderator cleanup. They may get rude. Or just wildly off-topic to the answer itself.

However, **what are my rules of thumb for flagging-or-not comment threads** that get out of hand length-wise (20+ comments), yet don't actually exhibit any overt issues in the comment contents *other than the comment count*? For example, most of the comments are pertinent to the answer; generally cordial and (subjectively judged) mostly useful-ish.

If it matters, the specific context is: assume the answer is mine; and I'm ***NOT*** bothered by proliferation of inbox pings from sheer counts.

Comment: Why would you want to delete content that you believe is, "pertinent to the answer; generally cordial and mostly useful-ish"?  Sounds like that's stuff that's *valuable* and that you want to keep.

Comment: @Servy - that's the thing, I am not sure I should want to delete it. But OTOH generally overly long comment threads tend to lose usefulness due to TL;DR

Comment: If they help you and haven't lost usefulness then don't flag them. Otherwise, flag them.

Comment: @DVK Sure, a long comment thread with useful information is *less likely* to be read than a shorter one.  A comment thread that is deleted because you flag it is *even less likely* to get read, and thus that useful information is *even less* likely to be seen.

Comment: (Also remember that, *ideally*, over time, comment votes tend to increase the visibility of the more helpful comments. Not all of the comments on a long comment thread are initially displayed, only the highest voted ones. And if there's key info there, feel free to edit it into the post.)

Comment: Hint: you could instead request the comments to be moved to chat room, with its own advantages and disadvantages... (At least that's what I got when I flagged once for comment cleanup. Not the one I expected, but it worked, so..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to make a set of concrete criteria that covers every situation in general. However, a general rule of thumb is still pretty simple:

Logically speaking...

- The purpose of cleaning up comments is to prevent noise that detracts from the quality and readability of the post and hinders constructive discussion, for the typical user.
- You are a typical user.

Therefore...

- You should flag comments for cleanup if they create noise that detracts from the quality and readability of the post and hinders constructive discussion, for *you*.

There's not much more to it. I wouldn't overthink it. If you look at a post and you find the comments to be problematic for *you*, then there's a good chance they'll be problematic for others, and so, flag it. If you look at a post and you find the comments to be helpful, then don't flag it. If you find only certain comments are problematic, then flag them individually.

Also, in all cases, if you find some helpful info in comments, don't forget you can edit those additional details into the post.

Comment: Why does the advice in the last line only applies to your own post?

Comment: "You are a typical user" - citation needed

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm open to better wording suggestions if the point is unclear. The general point I'm trying to make is: Don't overthink it; if you find the comments problematic then definitely flag them. If you don't then don't. That is, rather than trying to predict how others will react, base it on your *own* reactions, because if everybody does this, then in the bigger picture everything will end up in a state that the community is satisfied with. The OP's conflict is *they* aren't bothered by it, but weren't sure if they should flag it anyways.

Answer (score 7):

If twenty comments are left on some post within three days, a moderator flag is raised automatically. Therefore, there is no need to flag because of this.